# When I run "expo init my-app" I can't build a project with expo (React Native and Node)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

When I try to run "expo init my-new-project" in my console i=I get these massage after choosing "blank" or "tab" option.

```
? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
? Please enter a few initial configuration values.
Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/ » 50% completed
{
"expo": {
"name": "<The name of your app visible on the home screen>",
"slug": "my-app"
}
}
```

I tried everything but this is still happening. How can I can properly install it or what is the next step if I see this massage?

Answer (score 3):

When you receive such a phrase, you type a character on your keyboard and enter it into name(). If Yarn is installed, ask if you want to install it with yarn and write down Yes to complete the installation. The words will appear as shown in the following picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it's solved. so If you don't mind, can you choose my answer?

Comment: Yes, I choose your answer and already fix it, but face another problems still now.

Comment: What kind of trouble did you have?

Comment: I am already install latest venison of virtual box, genymotion emulator and properly install expo in my "c:\repos" now when I click run on emulator from expo cli I get this error. "Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory."

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348690/expo-cli-and-adb-error-can-not-connect-to-daemon

Comment: The answer has been attached to the link.

Comment: If it worked out well, would you please click on my answer to select it?

Comment: Hey @Navdisenyo check out my answer ! I m sure you can understand .

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did? 
At first, you need to install `npm install -g expo-cli` into your root directory. Then you will see this [image] image. Just press **Enter** then you can change the **"name"**  and **"displayName"** . See the image! Change the **name** then press down arrow button to come next then change the **"displayName"** then press **Enter**. Then see this [image] , Write **Y** then **Enter** .Then you are got to go ... Then see this image [image] .
Now easy part `cd yourprojectname` then `npm start`. 
Enjoy using expo 
For more info -[Getting started expo cli](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) and [Config Json](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/) (No need now)