# expo cli and ADB error: can not connect to daemon

Tags: react-native, npm, nodes, expo, genymotion

I am trying to get expo CLI and ADB working on my PC (Win 10 64bit) with the Genymotion emulator Google Pixel 3.

When I run "on android device/ emulator from expo cli" I get the following logs:

> Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

[See this image](http://%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/HabJZ.pngi)

I am already install latest verson of Virtual Box, genymotion emulator and properly install expo in my "c:\repos" now when I click run on emulator from expo cli I get this error. sdk manager is already install in my c:\ and in genymotion settings I setup this path in adb : "C:/Program Files/Genymobile/Genymotion" and it's show this folder is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error occurred because the current computer and emulator are not connected.

Did you set up the Genymotion as described in the error?

If you hadn't, go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools" ->

and point it at your Android SDK directory.

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

Run emulator, click  `developer options`, enable `USB debugging` and enable `Wi-Fi to Cellular`.

Run the `Genymotion Shell` and type `devices list` to find the IP address of the device.

Open the terminal and enter `adb connect deviceIp:5555`. Make sure the connection to `adb device` is correct. Enter `adb usb` and `adb tcpip 5555`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I am face still other one problems, now when emulator run show this error:    Trying to add a root view with an explicit id already set. React Native uses the id field to track react tags and will overwrite this field. If that is fine, explicitly overwrite the id field to View.NO_ID before calling addRootView.
addRootViewGroup
    NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:423
addRootView
    NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:418
addRootView
    UIViewOperationQueue.java:662
registerRootView....

Comment: This kind of error usually disappears when you click Reload.

Comment: If you liked my answer, please check my answer. Click on the "check(V)" sign.

Comment: can you please help me how to check your answer? "check(V) ??

Comment: also one thing more now see this error :  The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://192.168.56.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=C%3A%5CRepos%5Cmstore-3.6.4%5Cmstore-expo%5Cnode_modules%5Cexpo%5Ctools%5ChashAssetFiles.js

Body:
{"type":"TransformError","lineNumber":0,"errors":[{"description":"C:\\Repos\\mstore-3.6.4\\mstore-expo\\App.js: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null","lineNumber":0}],"name":"SyntaxError","message":"C:\\Repos\\mstore-3.6.4\\mstore-expo\\App.js:

Comment: C:\Repos\mstore-3.6.4\mstore-expo\node_modules\expo\build\environment\logging.js: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null

Comment: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/3937#issuecomment-411798745 Please refer to this link.

Comment: I was asking you to press the v sign below this picture(< 1 >) on the right.

Comment: are you want to say need to change/ fix package.json: file ?

Comment: for check my file please see this: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/3937#issuecomment-479779703

Comment: can you change code? `import { Font, Asset, AppLoading } from 'expo';`

Comment: Why did you write @?

Comment: I'm download this code from GitHub, however I fix it thank you.